# Can i use Pickit serial analyzer to debug stm32 microcontroller?

Tags: debugging, controller, stm32, stm32f4discovery, st-link

is it possible to use "Pickit" serial analyzer to debug stm32 microcontroller ? i am stuck in this.
need help.

Answer (score 1):

It depends that what do you mean by debugging. If you mean using `JTAG` to debug the microcontroller, the `Pickit` doesn't support that. But you can use other protocols to analyze the microcontroller. For example, you can send what you want to monitor using one of the supported protocols and analyze it using `Pickit` and its software.
According to [official website](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/development-tool/DV164122), currently these protocols are supported:

- I2C™ - Master
- I2C™ - Slave
- SPI - Master
- USART – Asynchronous
- USART – Synchronous
- LIN (external hardware required to meet electrical specifications)
- MICROWIRE